# cannot find symbol sshCloneUrl for cloning repository in bamboo-specs

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

I am working on writing Bamboo Specs for a build plan where i am trying to clone the repository from bitbucket. Here is my Spec code for Java

```
package tutorial;

import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.BambooSpec;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.AtlassianModule;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.BambooKey;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.BambooOid;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.Variable;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.applink.ApplicationLink;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.permission.PermissionType;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.permission.Permissions;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.permission.PlanPermissions;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.Job;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.Plan;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.PlanIdentifier;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.Stage;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.artifact.Artifact;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.artifact.ArtifactSubscription;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.branches.BranchCleanup;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.branches.PlanBranchManagement;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.configuration.AllOtherPluginsConfiguration;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.configuration.ConcurrentBuilds;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.project.Project;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.repository.VcsChangeDetection;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.task.AnyTask;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.repository.bitbucket.server.BitbucketServerRepository;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.repository.viewer.BitbucketServerRepositoryViewer;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.task.CheckoutItem;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.task.CommandTask;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.task.MsBuildTask;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.task.ScriptTask;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.task.VcsCheckoutTask;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.trigger.BitbucketServerTrigger;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.model.task.ScriptTaskProperties;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.util.BambooServer;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.util.MapBuilder;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.deployment.*;



/**
 * Plan configuration for Bamboo.
 * Learn more on: <a href="https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+Specs">https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+Specs</a>
 */
@BambooSpec
public class PlanSpec {

    /**
     * Run main to publish plan on Bamboo
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        //By default credentials are read from the '.credentials' file.
        BambooServer bambooServer = new BambooServer("http://localhost:8085");

        Plan plan = new PlanSpec().createPlan();
        Deployment deploy = new PlanSpec().createDeployment();
        bambooServer.publish(plan);
        bambooServer.publish(deploy);

        PlanPermissions planPermission = new PlanSpec().createPlanPermission(plan.getIdentifier());

        bambooServer.publish(planPermission);
    }


    PlanPermissions createPlanPermission(PlanIdentifier planIdentifier) {
        Permissions permission = new Permissions()
                .groupPermissions("bamboo-admin", PermissionType.ADMIN)
                .anonymousUserPermissionView();
        return new PlanPermissions(planIdentifier.getProjectKey(), planIdentifier.getPlanKey()).permissions(permission);
    }

    Project project = new Project().name("Bamboo Specs").key("DRAGON");


    Plan createPlan() {
        return new Plan(
                project,
                "Java Specs Plan 2", "JSPTT2")
                .description("Plan created from (enter repository url of your plan)")
                .planRepositories(new BitbucketServerRepository()
                        .name("New Pattern Playbook")
                        .repositoryViewer(new BitbucketServerRepositoryViewer())
                        .server(new ApplicationLink()
                                .name("Bitbucket")
                                .id("bca01bef-a3d8-3da3-9187-91b73d0f1f77"))
                        .projectKey("ALM")
                        .repositorySlug("pattern.dotnet")
                        .sshPublicKey("ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC2ETaXXCvEeZqcJWxybcMA91jiskcjrh5PB2UqLNenhiGRdh2kZBUgBMur/JsBYzFF2tNTlWdOXW1oRhSQ38PeUGXVRg3pMR5mxvOO/K/wO1DB6ZqjzRgwLFBJJMqCk58I213Y2pvd7Q9ot/xLludzh3rKmJFHwqOOBJYO/BLIqwL/hfM2Kvr4Op/284s5vBhJ+4l8sCrorSGsDE/r7mpAWjvrMGZGosLqgQtvrnzrL9XchxMT8UstzVeIAdHtWcwGOtv+1pjAqW6+035A/5W3tsWJ+EyBWFQ4rkZP/HFEdAAUgpM//oNVfB03+zZVn0BIKWX6evcwQPEjVzqn3+Ir http://bamboo-lab.cdk.com")
                        .sshPrivateKey("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\ntEJaTQdg/yXvnKpKCAtp+KJVfLyuRtuPwppR3yIGfpJNMYxUxHRb\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n")
                        .sshCloneUrl("ssh://git@stash-lab.cdk.com:7999/alm/pattern.dotnet.git")
                        .remoteAgentCacheEnabled(false)
                        .changeDetection(new VcsChangeDetection()))
                .stages(new Stage("Stage 1")
                        .jobs(new Job("First Job","JOB1")
                                .tasks(new ScriptTask()
                                        .inlineBody("echo Hello World")
                                )));
    }



    Deployment createDeployment() {
        return new Deployment(new PlanIdentifier("DRAGON", "JSPTT"),
                "Java Specs Plan Deployment")
                .releaseNaming(new ReleaseNaming("release-1")
                        .autoIncrement(true))
                .environments(new Environment("Java Specs environment")
                        .tasks(new ScriptTask().inlineBody("echo Hello world!")));
    }


}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/kamblea/Documents/REPOS/bamboo-spec/java/bamboospecjava/bamboo-specs/src/main/java/tutorial/PlanSpec.java:[90,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method sshCloneUrl(java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   location: class com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.builders.repository.bitbucket.server.BitbucketServerRepository
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it on my own.

Solution: I am using Bamboo version 6.3.1 and trying to use Bamboo Specs 6.4 version which is only compatible with Bamboo 6.4 and higher version.

So, I refer the older API reference to solve this issue and it worked.